# How to alter CSS files inside aikau-1.0.101.10.jar in Alfresco

Tags: css, alfresco, alfresco-share, aikau

I was working on translating Alfresco share to Arabic i.e to RTL format.

Reading a comment from [here](https://issues.alfresco.com/jira/browse/REPO-1056?focusedCommentId=384009&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-384009) I found out that the best way to proceed is to  Create a custom extension pulling in an additional CSS file with the styling modifications.

Now coming to the question, I've encountered a problem while altering the css files to support RTL. The problem was that some css files were situated inside aikau-1.0.101.10.jar file. Can anyone help me on how to alter these css files ? or Can I override these files somehow ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some ways to do this:

1. You can create your own theme
2. Override LESS variable [link](https://docs.alfresco.com/5.2/tasks/dev-extensions-share-tutorials-customize-header-style.html)
3. Fork Aikau and build your own jar [link](https://github.com/Alfresco/Aikau)
4. Create an extension to include your own css file [link](https://community.alfresco.com/thread/185224-extension-module-to-customize-login-css)

Comment: **Override LESS variable** and **You can create your own theme** Answering on these..

I did try to create an own custom theme and overide the LESS variable. But this does not work for my problem. The LESS variables are only been there for the **css attributes** such as for **color** and **background color**. What I'm trying to do is to change the direction attributes such as **float:right** to **float:left** and so on.

Comment: And for the other one i.e **Create an extension to include your own css file** using this too I think I wouldn't be able to override the css files in the aikau-1.0.101.10.jar. As I've read and understood from this (https://community.alfresco.com/thread/185224-extension-module-to-customize-login-css) link is that, you can add your custom css to the custom page created [for example: the login page that the person is trying to create].

Comment: **Fork Aikau and build your own jar**  This method would probably work, but is there no other ways of making this possible?